# Concatenate variable at end of formula as opposed to within VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to escape the end of this formula. Normally not a big deal, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to approach this with a trailing variable:

```
.Range(CampaignRange).Formula = "=" & campaignValue "
```

campaignValue is the variable in this instance.

I tried leaving the end quote, but throws an error:

```
.Range(CampaignRange).Formula = "=" & campaignValue
```

How does one concatenate an ending variable?

Comment: What error is thrown? What does `campaignValue` contains?

Comment: The value of a cell :

campaignValue = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(MainSheet).Cells(4, 2).Value

Comment: And what does `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(MainSheet).Cells(4, 2).Value` contains? And what error is thrown?

Comment: Syntax error and Example campaign 1

Comment: If `campaignValue` is just a value, why don't you just say `.Range(campaignRange).Value = campaignValue`?

Comment: I think I'm what's affectionately called – a moron.

Much appreciated and much better solution. It's late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `campaignValue` contains a string such as "Example campaign 1", and you want to create an Excel formula of

```
="Example campaign 1"
```

then you need to use

```
.Range(CampaignRange).Formula = "=""" & campaignValue & """"
```

so that the double-quotation marks are included in the formula.

---

But you will probably find it easier just to say

```
.Range(CampaignRange).Value = campaignValue
```